# Easy way to get comma seperate value from the array using PHP

Tags: php

I have this variable $sid and its output is below.

```
$sid    =   $_POST['sid'];
// sid consists values like this.
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2,3
)
```

now I need to run a query with this sid 1, 2 and 3. To do that I am using following code:

```
$ex = array();
foreach ( $sid as $key => $value) {
    $ex[] = explode(',', $value);
}


foreach ($ex as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        echo $v;
        // my query where sid =  $v
    }
}
```

Is there any better way without multiple `foreach` loop?

Comment: store all id and get data using single query. use WHERE IN($ids_array)

Comment: You could nest the loops

Comment: Guys, I don't get you :(

Comment: using 2 foreaches on 2 dimensional array is ok

Comment: @Universus okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ex = explode(',', implode(',', $sid));

foreach ($ex as $v) {
    echo $v;
}
```

Basically, your input is an array of strings of comma-separated values, so, you can merge these strings into single string with comma as separator, and then split whole thing using single `explode` call.

Comment: Perfect solution :) :) :)

Comment: Well, not really perfect, as it does not check for special cases like empty `$_POST['sid']`. But your original code does not do that either, so, this is probably a perfect replacement which can be improved.

Comment: exactly I need to validate the data.